# Talmud Yerushalmi Halachot

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, talmud-yerushalmi

The halacha we have today is mostly sourced in Talmud Bavli(the Babylonian Talmud),Medrash and Zohar.  I would like to know what Halachot which we have today which are sourced strictly in the Yerushalmi (the Jerusalem Talmud) and where they can be found in the Yerushalmi. Any Halacha would be appreciated.

Comment: Great resource article on this topic THANKS too YDK

Comment: http://torahmusings.com/2011/05/the-yerushalmi-as-a-source-of-halacha/

Comment: This question is a subset of this one: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13058/472.

Comment: @DoubleAA is this on topic or is it a riddle or too broad?

Comment: @mevaqesh I don't know that it's any of those but it might be http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/959/759

Answer (score 8):

The answers to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12605/is-there-any-issue-with-using-aerosols-on-shabbos) refer to a Yerushalmi (Shabbos 7:2) that extends the melachah of זורה (winnowing) to scattering something in the wind (the example given is spitting). This is cited as halachah in Rema, Orach Chaim, end of sec. 319,17

But see the Mishna Brura quoting Rabbi Akiva Eiger that its permitted to spit on Shabbos as one is not intending to Winnow at all and this is not how one normally winnows.

> מפזר הרוק - ולא ראינו מי שחושש לזה כיון דאינו מתכוין לכך וכ"ש דאין זה דרך זורה [חידושי רע"א]

Comment: You might want to look at the Mishna Brura who says we don't pasken like this Rema that it is permitted to spit on Shabbos

Comment: This particular halachah is interesting because the poskim discuss how to understand if the Bavli's not mentioning the issue means it disagrees with the Yerushalmi or not. Yalkut Yosef, for example, says that because the Bavli gives a different explanation of the melachah of zoreh this Yerushalmi should not be followed. (Leaving aside the question of whether the Rema even makes sense based on the Yerushalmi).

Answer (score 8):

The Shulchan Aruch rules in OC 448:6 that you can't feed chametz to an ownerless animal based on Yerushalmi Pesachim 2:1

Answer (score 8):

So so so many laws of Zeraim as there is no Bavli on that order of Mishna.

[I know this isn't specific, but I wanted to put it out there]

One example  is in [Yore Dea 331,137](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.331.137?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) the *Bracha* for transferring sanctity of *Maaser Sheini* onto money is mentioned in [Yerushalmi Demai 1,4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jerusalem_Talmud_Demai.5b.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> אקב"ו על פדיון מעשר שני

Comment: It is a great point but there are limited references to Zeraim in Bavli like Moed katan and Shmeitah among the prominent ones

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7165/why-no-talmud-bavli-on-zeraim-or-taharot

Answer (score 5):

In Hilchot Mezuza (Yore Deah 285) the Rama rules like Rav Huna in the Yerushalmi Megilla 4,12  that if one can only buy Tefilin or Mezuza, he should buy Tefilin.

Comment: where is the Yerushalmi?

Comment: @simchashatorah the fourth chapter in the Vilna version I believe.

Comment: All versions have the same chapters

Answer (score 4):

From the [Rabbi Broyde post](http://torahmusings.com/2011/05/the-yerushalmi-as-a-source-of-halacha/) that I referenced in a comment to your [un-duplicate question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13058/yerushalmi-versus-bavli-in-halacha):

> Consider, for example, four examples that I happen to have written
>   about or am writing about currently—tefillin on Chol ha-Moed, aliyot
>   in a city where all the men are kohanim, whether the daughter of a
>   gentile man and Jewish woman may marry a Kohen, and the of using
>   charity funds to build synagogues rather than to support the poor.
>
> In all four cases, the Bavli is silent while the Yerushalmi directly
>   addresses the matter. On the topic of tefillin on Chol ha-Moed, Y.Moed
>   Katan 3:4 is clear that tefillin should be worn; in Y.Gittin 5:9 it is
>   clear that even in a city where all the men are kohanim, women do not
>   get called to the Torah; Y.Yevamot 4:15 is clear that such a woman
>   cannot marry a Kohen; and in Y.Peah 8:8 it is clear that a synagogue
>   is a valid recipient of charity. Although it is obvious that each of
>   these four matters generates some controversy among the Poskim, I
>   suspect that the core dispute is whether one needs to adopt the
>   halachic norm as expressed by the Jerusalem Talmud. Much more could be
>   written on this matter.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Yerushalmi (Megillah 1:9), letters in Sta"m need to be mukaf gevil (surrounded by white parchment) on the inside of the letter as well (eg a the inside of a samech). See Shulchan Aruch OC 32:15

Comment: Since when is gevil white?

Comment: @Aaron since we isolated tannic acid from gallnut juice :) contemporary tan gevil generally has added colors. but seriously white doesn't mean pure white. It's still called black on white writing even if the paper is off white.

Answer (score 2):

The Rambam Hilchos Shofar 2,8 says that the during the time of the Beis Hamikdash they would blow the Shofar on Shabbos in Yerushalayim and all the surrounding cities that were in eyesight of Yerushalayim becaue they knew of the fixing of Rosh Chodesh

> בזמן שהיה בית המקדש קיים והיה בית דין הגדול בירושלים היו הכל תוקעין בירושלים בשבת כל זמן שבית דין יושבין. ולא אנשי ירושלים בלבד אלא כל עיר שהיתה בתוך תחום ירושלים

The Mirkeves Hamishne says that the source of the Rambam is in the Yerushalmi Rosh Hashana 4,1:

> סמך רבנו על הירושלמי היוצא מזה לפי טעמו של רשב"י פי' המשנה אפילו בירושלים נמי תוקעין כיון דידעי בקביעא דירחי

see here for a full explanation [Torah prohibition of Shofar on Shabbos Rosh Hashanah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/95297/torah-prohibition-of-shofar-on-shabbos-rosh-hashanah/98333#98333)

Comment: ‘The halacha we have today is mostly sourced in Talmud Bavli(the Babylonian Talmud),Medrash and Zohar. I would like to know what Halachot which we have today which are sourced strictly in the Yerushalmi’

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Bimheira Yibane Beis Hamikdash

Comment: We have faith that this Halacha will be needed for the coming Rosh Hashana

Comment: @user15464 The coming Rosh Hashana is on a Monday.

Comment: @heshy if Moshiach comes tomorrow then we would need to wait for eidim to come so if 2 of the months that are 29 days on the fixed calender there are no eidim that saw the new moon and those months were 30 days instead then Rosh Hashono could indeed fall on SHabbos

Comment: @user15464 it's the opposite.  Two of the days that are 30 days on the fixed calendar would have to be 29 days, with no extra 30 day months to compensate.  Rosh Hashana can't happen until the day the witnesses see the moon of Tishrei, which can't happen until after 9:26 PM Saturday night Israel time.  https://www.timeanddate.com/moon/phases/  Rosh Hashana might be Sunday, but it's definitely not going to be Shabbos.

Answer (score 1):

**[Orach Chaim 240](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.240.12?vhe=Maginei_Eretz:_Shulchan_Aruch_Orach_Chaim,_Lemberg,_1893&lang=bi&with=Beur%20HaGra&lang2=he)**

> אסור לשמש מטתו בשני רעבון אלא לחשוכי בנים [פירוש מי שאין לו בנים] הגה וע"ל סי' תקע"ד ס"ד וה"ה בשאר צרות שהם כרעבון [ירושלמי דתענית]
>
> One may not have intercourse in times of hardship, because they are akin to famine-stricken years.

Biur HaGra sources it in [Ta'nit 1.6](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r29.htm) ([7a](https://www.sefaria.org/Job.30.3?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Jerusalem_Talmud_Ta%27anit.7a.1&lang2=bi))

> סי"ב וה"ה כו'. ירושלמי א"ר אבין כתיב [בחוסר ובכפן גלמוד](https://www.sefaria.org/Job.30?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi) בשעה שאתה רואה חסרון בא לעולם עשה אשתך [גלמודה](https://www.sefaria.org/Jastrow%2C_%D7%92%D6%B7%D6%BC%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%9E%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%93%D6%B8%D7%90.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

Comment: Nice answer i always assumed this was a Rashi quoting Medrash Rabba on Parshas Vayigash that Yosef only had his 2 children before the famine

Comment: @user15464 read the yerushalmi on

Comment: @drshmuel i think Rashi says somewhere that Bereishis Rabba is Medrash of Eretz Yisroel so that might explain the identical passages that appear in both

Comment: The question did say a Halacha uniquely from the Yerushalmi without any source elsewhere, so if this is also in medrash Bereishis Raba it's not so unique

Comment: Do we have Halacha strictly from any medrashim at all? It seems that there is often a backing as a second reference as in Zohar, too @yosef

Answer (score 1):

Rambam Choveil umazik 1:11, Rif and almost all rishonim on Bava kamma 26b quoting the Yerushalmi halacha 2,8:

> במה דברים אמורים שהישן חייב לשלם בשנים שישנו כאחד ונתהפך אחד מהן והזיק את חבירו או קרע בגדו. אבל אם היה אחד ישן ובא אחר ושכב בצדו. זה שבא באחרונה הוא המועד ואם הזיקו הישן פטור

When is a person liable to damages when "not at fault" i.e oneis in a case when flailing in his sleep and whacking the fellow next to him? If he slept next to someone else sleeping and did damage. But he is not liable when flailing in his sleep if that person only went to sleep next to him after he was already asleep because the latter is responsible for putting himself in a position of damage i.e oneis gommur

Answer (score 1):

Rama [(290)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.290.2) references the Talmud Yerushalmi in Shabbos [(78a, 15:3)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14141&pgnum=160&hilite=), quoted in Beis Yosef (288) and cited by the Mishna Berurah (290:7).

Rema 290

> אחר סעודת שחרית קובעים מדרש לקרות בנביאים ולדרוש בדברי אגדה ואסור לקבוע סעודה באותה שעה: הגה ופועלים ובעלי בתים שאינן עוסקים בתורה כל ימי שבוע יעסקו יותר בתורה בשבת מתלמידי חכמים העוסקים בתורה כל ימי השבוע ותלמידי חכמים ימשיכו יותר בעונג אכילה ושתיה קצת שהרי מתענגים בלמודם כל ימי השבוע: [ב"י סי' רפ"ח בשם ירושלמי]:
>
> After the morning meal, we establish learning, to read in Prophets and expound on Agada. And it is forbidden to establish a meal during that time. Haga: And workers and homeowners who do not toil in Torah during all the days of the week, should toil more in Torah on Shabbos than Torah scholars who toil in Torah all days of the week. And the Torah scholars should engross more in the enjoyment of eating and drinking, a bit, because they pleasure in their studies all days of the week.

Shabbos 78a

> רבי חגי בשם רבי שמואל בר נחמן לא ניתנו שבתות וימים טובים אלא לאכילה ולשתייה. על ידי שהפה זה מסריח התירו לו לעסוק בהן בדברי תורה. רבי ברכיה בשם רבי חייא בר בא לא ניתנו שבתות וימים טובים אלא לעסוק בהן בדברי תורה.

Answer (score 0):

The Rambam allowed a convert to say “God of our fathers” in prayers, which a convert was, up to that point, not allowed to say, because his “fathers” were not Jewish.  Indeed, the Mishna in Bikkurim does not allow it.  [The Babylonian Talmud (the Bavli) has no Gemara in Bikkurim, and hence accepts the Mishna]:

> The convert brings [first fruits] but does not recite [the relevant declaration in Deuteronomy] because he cannot say “the land which God has sworn to our fathers to give us.” [Deuteronomy 26:3].  But if his mother was of Israel, he may [both] bring [first fruits] and recite [the declaration].  And when he prays by himself, he says, “God of the fathers of Israel”.  And when he is in synagogue [with the community], he says, “God of YOUR fathers.” But if his mother was of Israel, he says, “God of our fathers.” [B. Bikkurim 1:4]

But the Jerusalem Talmud (the Yerushalmi) allows it!

> A… convert brings [first fruits] AND recites [the declaration in Deuteronomy].  Why?  [Because God said to Abraham]:  “For I have made you the father of a multitude of nations” [Genesis 17:5]. In the past you were a father to Aram [only], but now, henceforth, you are a father to all the nations. [J. Bikkurim 1:4, 64a]

Normally, when the two Talmuds differ the Bavli wins.  But Maimonides ruled in favor of the Yerushalmi.  In his letter to a convert named Obadiah, he says:

> You ask me if you, too, are allowed to say… “Our God and God of our fathers”, “who has sanctified us through His commandments”, “who has separated us”, “who has chosen us”, “who has given to our fathers to inherit [a pleasant, good and spacious land]”, “who has brought us out of the Land of Egypt”, “who has worked miracles to our fathers”, and more of this kind.  Yes, you may say all this in the prescribed order and not change it in the least…

And he concludes:

> Toward father and mother we are commanded to honor and revere them, toward the prophets to obey them, but toward converts we are commanded to have great love in our inmost hearts.... God, in His glory, loves a convert --... [because he is] a man who left his father and birthplace and the realm of his people at a time when they are powerful, who understood with his insight, and who attached himself to this nation which today is a despised people, the slave of rulers, and recognized and knew that their religion is true and righteous... and pursued God... and entered beneath the wings of the Divine Presence...  [Letter to Obadiah the Convert]

The debate continued.  It took four centuries for the Rambam’s position to be universally accepted.

Comment: I see no evidence here the Bavli disagrees with the Yerushalmi

Comment: The absence of a gemara in the Bavli is tacit acceptance of the Mishna, and that was how it was interpreted until the Rambam came along.

Comment: I disagree. The absence of a gemara in the Bavli is entirely inconclusive. It's an absence of evidence.

Comment: If so, why did the people ignore the gemara in the Yerushalmi for so long?

Comment: Maybe they just ruled like the Mishna without assuming the Bavli took a position? This is after all a Machloket Tannaim already. And what's your evidence that everyone ignored it?

Comment: "Maybe they just ruled like the Mishna without assuming the Bavli took a position".  1-You mean "the Yerushalmi took a position"?  2-The Rambam would not have had to rule on the matter if it was already being done.

Comment: 1) I don't concede the Yerushalmi took a position. All you've shown is a position is quoted in the Yerushalmi. No reason to think the Babylonians didn't know that other position too. 2) Indeed rabbis never answer but the most revolutionary of questions