# If someone doesn't believe in the Gemara, is he a heretic?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, talmud-gemara, mishna, heresy, oral-torah

If someone says "I believe that the Mishnayos/Braisos/Toseftas are accurate, but I think that the Gemara made mistakes and has no holiness.

Is such philosophy heresy?

What about someone who argues on specific Mishnas?

What about someone who argues on ALL the Mishnas (he believes that there was an Oral Torah, but it got forgotten)?

Comment: 'made mistakes' and 'has no holiness' are different claims.

Comment: Do you mean Bavli or Yerushalmi?

Comment: What do mean the Mishna etc. is accurate? That it is an [absolute truth](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9093/759)?

Comment: then: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13058/759

Comment: It would be best to clarify exactly what you mean in the question itself. Consider also including if the content of the argued-about Mishna includes things like traditions from Sinai, matters of interpretation of pesukim or of rabbinic decrees, historical assertions, scientific assertions etc.

Answer (score 2):

כופר בתורה שבעל פה does not mean that he denies the theoretical existence of any תורה שבע"פ but that he denies the actual תורה שבע"פ in our possession--so if someone denies the authentic תורה שבע"פ he would fall under that category. Furthermore, such a person would be included under the category of מכחיש מגידיה as someone who denies the reliability of the bearers of our tradition (Rambam, Hil. Teshuvah 3:8).

However, Rashi in Shabbat 31a explains the case of the gentile who came to Hillel to convert and said he did not accept the Oral Law:
שלא היה כופר בתורה שבעל פה אלא שלא היה מאמין שהיא מפי הגבורה. R. Moshe Feinstein (Dibberot Moshe, Yevamot, p. 477; Iggerot Moshe, vol. 9, YD 41:2) explains Rashi's comment to mean that the potential convert did not believe that what Hillel was teaching him was part of the actual Oral Law transmitted by God, but did believe in the existence of such an Oral Law. According to R. Moshe's interpretation of Rashi, it is possible that such a person would not be considered a heretic.

Comment: Is every line of Gemara a received tradition from Sinai?

Comment: oh you're answering his last question.