# Talmud comes from Har Sinai?

Tags: oral-torah, har-sinai

I recently heard from an unreliable source that a certain Chasidic rabbi in my hometown claims that the entire oral Torah in its current written form (including the Bavli, the Yerushalmi, and all of the Torah she'b'al'peh that came later) was given at Har Sinai and passed down orally verbatim until it was finally written down.

I am pretty sure that the person who I heard this from is mistaken because I have never heard anybody make such a claim, but that's why I am asking here whether there is any group or authority who make this claim?

Comment: "Wow", said Rabbah bar bar Channah, as his teacher relayed to him what would be the future TB Bava Basra 73-75, "I am going to get up to some pretty weird stuff, it seems."

Comment: Would this mean that we have to treat every takana and gezeira derabanan as a halacha leMoshe miSinai?

Comment: @IsaacMoses, that's an interesting question even if we don't accept this assumption as true. We believe that Torah she'b'al peh comes from Har Sinai (even if not word-for-word), so where do all of the takanas, etc. come from?

Comment: @Daniel, who ever (besides the rabbi in the rumor) said that enactments of the Rabbis are ToShB"A (in the sense of what we got at Sinai along with Scripture), *per se*?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I don't think there is any claim that he considers the Oral Torah to be any different from what others consider the Oral Torah. Although, if there is no such thing as a real chiddush, as SethJ mentions in his answer, they must be in there somewhere.

Comment: By "they" I mean the takanas, gezeiras derabanan, etc.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23343/does-rambam-include-the-oral-torah-in-his-eighth-principle/23344#comment54790_23344

Comment: @Daniel, It's a contradiction in terms to say that takanot and gezeirot are anything other than chiddushim. David Hamelech did not send mishloach manot on the 14th of Adar. In so not doing, he was not missing the fulfillment of a positive commandment. Until the gezeirot of Mordechai and Esther, there was no such commandment, and now there is. That's chiddush. Any concept of "there's no chiddush" or "it all came verbatim at Sinai" that doesn't exclude derabanans has *a lot* to explain away and is not something I'd accept as even possibly valid without a solid source.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I agree with you. Apparently some people don't, though. And apparently they have some basis in gemarra (I can't check it now).

Comment: [Shemot Rabba 47:1](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/tanach/raba2/47.htm)?

Comment: @DoubleAA Sounds on-point: "בשעה שעלה הקמש ב״ה בסיני ליתן תורה לישראל אמרה למשה על הסדר מקרא ומשנה תלמוד ואגדה שנא׳ (שמות כ) וידבר אלהים את כל הדברים האלה אפילו מה שהתלמיד שואל לרב אמר הקרוש ב״ה למשה באותה שעה"

Comment: @IsaacMoses Also sounds allegorical.

Comment: @IsaacMoses: Megilla 19B http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=19b&format=pdf -- ואמר ר' חייא בר אבא א"ר יוחנן מאי דכתיב ועליהם ככל הדברים אשר דבר ה' עמכם בהר מלמד שהראהו הקב"ה למשה דקדוקי תורה ודקדוקי סופרים ומה שהסופרים עתידין לחדש ומאי ניהו מקרא מגילה

Comment: @Menachem Also very on-point.

Comment: @Menachem http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/66135 This source seems to exclude all rabbinic enactments _except_ megillah.

Comment: @DoubleAA: See the footnote at the bottom of page 31, 32 of http://books.google.co.cr/books?id=r54bbqIYAZgC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA31#v=onepage&q&f=false -- A long list of sources for the statement "‫כל מה שתלמיד ותיק עתיד‬‫ לחדש ככר ניתן למשה מסיני‬" (which is slightly different than the gemara and midrashic sources mentioned in this thread)

Comment: @IsaacMoses: with regards to your first question, see point 5 in this answer: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4078/avot-keeping-mitzvot/8242#8242

Comment: Now you have a problem: every answer on Mi Yodeya needs to be accepted as they were all given to Moshe at Sinai and must be accurate!

Comment: I'm surprised to see that no one has cited the Talmud Bavli in Masekhet Berakhot 5A ([Original](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=5&format=pdf), [English](http://halakhah.com/pdf/zeraim/Berachoth.pdf)): "וא"ר לוי בר חמא אמר ר' שמעון בן לקיש מאי דכתיב ואתנה לך את לוחות האבן והתורה והמצוה אשר כתבתי להורותם לוחות אלו עשרת הדברות תורה זה מקרא והמצוה זו משנה אשר כתבתי אלו נביאים וכתובים להורותם זה גמרא מלמד שכולם נתנו למשה מסיני". I heard it from HaRav Eyal Wered of Makhon Me'ir (B"N will find citation) that there are many who interpret this Gemara quite literally.

Comment: @Lee There is a big distinction to be made between the ToSHB"A(P) and the content through which we learn said information (Talmud). While the information itself was conveyed at Sinai, the process through which the knowledge was later "reclaimed" wasn't. For examples: Yehoshua forgetting large swathes of ToSHB"A upon the death of Moshe, the midrash of Hashem showing Moshe R'Akiva and explaining that R"A's drashot were "contained" in the information handed Moshe and were not "new data," "gam zu Torah," etc. Basically Torah=\= Talmud, but Talmud "contains" the teaching of Torah, by and large.

Answer (score 6):

See [Yerushalmi Peah Perek 2 Halacha 4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r1202.htm), Shmos Rabbah Begining Parsha 47, Vayikrah Rabbah Begining Parsha 22 where it says that it was all said to Moshe at Har Sinai.

ריב"ל אמר עליהם ועליהם כל ככל דברים הדברים מקרא משנה תלמוד ואגדה אפי' מה שתלמיד ותיק עתיד להורות לפני רבו **כבר נאמר** למשה בסיני

For a lot on this subject please see [this and the following pages](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16009&st=&pgnum=407&hilite=)

Comment: Do you have any evidence that those midrashim you cite (which are identical to each other) are not clearly allegorical? Can you also source how you know it means the exact words of our talmuds/mishna/midrash and not the "highlights" or main content points of torah shebe'al peh?

Comment: I don't need to, if one has a complaint against someone who translates it literally he has to be the one to prove.

Comment: For reasons to suspect it is allegorical, see every other comment and answer on this page. The onus is on _you_.

Comment: Also the word להורות (which is the girsa in the yerushalmi) is odd. The girsaot of the Midrash sound much better: שואל (Exodus Rabba) or לומר (Lev. Rabba).

Comment: Does this statement include parts of the Talmud which appear to be from people who lived after R Yehoshua ben Levi?

Comment: Does this statement include parts of the Talmud which seem to have been written in the time of the Geonim?

Comment: @MeirZirkind Did Moshe Rabbeinu send Mishloach Manot on Purim?  If not, assuming he received the entire Oral Torah including the Gemarras, why not?  What about Tzom Gedeliah?  Tisha B'Av, 17th of Tammuz?

Comment: @RabbiMichaelTzadok Did Avraham Avinu send Mishloach Monos? Did he keep Eiruvin which Shlomo Hamelech instituted?

Comment: @MeirZirkind Did he read parshat zachor? did he write a Torah? did he know he was going to have a son at age 100? So why did he laugh? ||| We've all heard these questions before. I don't know why you bring them up, when we are not talking about the Avos. And by the way, Avraham probably did neither of those things, which would be meaningless, not having been enacted yet. Moshe certainly did neither.

Comment: @DoubleAA See Rashi to [Bereishis 26:6](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/showrashi/true/aid/8221/jewish/Chapter-26.htm#v5)

Comment: @Michoel So? I chose my examples and noted the examples he chose carefully.

Comment: @DoubleAA What d'rabanon did he keep, and which not?

Comment: @Michoel Why can't we hold like the Rambam, Ben Ish Hai, and other torah giants that said he only kept M'Doraitta and then only what made sense to him?

Comment: @Michoel According to Rashi: גזרות להרחקה על אזהרות שבתורה, כגון שניות לעריות ושבות לשבת: Mishloach Manos is clearly _not_ included. As for Eruvin, you might argue that Eruv Chatzerot is included, though he probably didn't do that either, having a din of Yachid (OC 382). And before you quote Eruv Tavshilin which Rashi is probably basing himself on, see this http://parsha.blogspot.com/2011/11/did-avraham-specifically-keep-eruv.html (Note also my switch from 'probably' to 'certainly' in my previous comment.)

Comment: @RabbiMichaelTzadok You can "hold like" whoever you want. That doesn't take away the fact that there is a very legitimate opinion that Avraham Avinu kept "shevus leshabas".

Comment: @Michoel I'd call it a school of thought, not an opinion. And while Rashi may make something 'legitimate' (whatever that means) that doesn't make him not a minority extreme opinion. (It doesn't make him into one either.)

Comment: @RabbiMichaelTzadok Because 'holding' (implying _psak_) is a funny word to apply to this kind of historical machloket.

Comment: @DoubleAA I've never heard that holding implies psak.  I've always heard it as the English translation for סובר or סברא.  That's how its used in the Yeshivish circles that I run in.

Comment: Here is a story in Gemara Sanhedrin 100a take it as you like: R. Johanan was sitting and teaching: The Holy One, blessed be He, will bring jewels and precious stones, each 30 cubits long, and 30 cubits high, and make an engraving in them, 10 by 20 cubits, and set them up as the gates of Jerusalem, for it is written, And I will make thy windows of agates, and thy gates of carbuncles. A certain disciple derided him saying, ‘We do not find a jewel even as large as a dove's egg, yet such huge ones are to exist!’  Cont.

Comment: Some time later he took a sea journey and saw the ministering angels cutting precious stones and pearls. He said unto them: ‘For what are these?’ They replied: ‘The Holy One, blessed be He, will set them up as the gates of Jerusalem.’ On his return, he found R. Johanan sitting and teaching. He said to him: ‘Expound, O Master, and it is indeed fitting for you to expound, for even as you did say, so did I myself see.’ ‘Wretch!’ he exclaimed, ‘had you not seen, you would not have believed! You deride the words of the Sages!’

Comment: @MeirZirkind If you want to quote Aggadata, how about the famous one in Mnochot about the Tagin.  Moshe Rabbeinu didn't understand them, but Rabbi Akiva would expound upon them.  See also the Maharal of Prague on that piece.  Most notably where he says the Moshe Rabbeinu was limited in the oral torah.

Comment: @RabbiMichaelTzadok I dont believe Rambam says they kept all d'oraysas.

Answer (score 3):

I have heard this, and not just in Chassidic circles.  However I cannot give you an actual source for it, as I have never found it written in a sefer, though I typically don't read Chassidic Sichot or some of the more radical and odd Midrashim.  [However here is a video that lays out fairly well the logic of both sides of the debate while being a bit comical.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8MG9YtaZXg&feature=share&list=PL31EBB912F1EFF9FA)  It is short rehash of a debate that took place in a blog thread.  Wherein one person made the claim that even the Avot knew and kept oral Torah, with the other side presenting the logical fallacies of that.

On a practical level Rav Treibitz (Talmid Muvhak of Rav Shternbuch and posek in Har Nof) lays out an interesting argument for the development of the Gemarra.  [Here is the first of I believe 20 total shiurim on the topic.](http://www.hashkafacircle.com/history-development-of-talmud-1/)  Rav Triebitz gives historical background arguing for the Gemarra being developed and written rather late with final codification being done around 850CE just before the end of the Geonim.

Comment: video discussed here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4078/avot-keeping-mitzvot/8242

Comment: @IsaacMoses added some explanation.

Comment: "Rav Treibitz (Talmid Muvhak of Rav Shternbuch)" I don't know that this is true. Do you? it is true that they have a positive relationship.

Answer (score 0):

My personal feeling is that, regardless of whether anyone actually made or makes this claim, it should be clear that it is nonsense.

What I have heard, and I cannot provide a source, unfortunately, is that all Torah was given to Moshe, and there is no such thing as a real "Chiddush", that is, any innovation.  Any "new" insights to the Torah are really just revealing the true meaning that was previously unknown or not clearly understood.

The only possible way the claim referenced in the question can be "true" is if one stretches the literal meaning of it to mean that G-d told Moshe everything, including what we have yet to learn or uncover, including debates among rabbis not yet known to us.

In other words, if taken literally, meaning it is *passed down*, all rabbis living today and engaging in debate should have some written source on their bookshelves somewhere with their names in it.  This would be very weird.

Comment: What do you mean by your last paragraph? Clearly not all rabbis living today and engaging in debate have their name written in some sefer.

Comment: @Daniel, well, that's how your question reads. "[T]he entire oral Torah in its current written form (including the Bavli, the Yerushalmi, and all of the Torah she'b'al'peh that came later was given at Har Sinai and passed down orally verbatim until it was finally written down."  Is that not the claim you're asking about?

Comment: Yes it is. I think I just don't understand the wording of the last paragraph. What are you trying to say?

Comment: +1. As to "all Torah was given to Moshe, and there is no such thing as a real 'Chiddush', that is, any innovation. Any 'new' insights to the Torah are really just revealing the true meaning that was previously unknown or not clearly understood", I think the _Bavli_ in _M'gila_ alludes to this, seeing it in a verse in _Ezra_, but I have the citation to neither at hand.

Comment: @Daniel, I'm not sure how I can be more clear. If every bit of Torah SheBe'al Peh was passed down word for word, that would necessarily include every Devar Torah and responsa written by R' Shternbuch, R' Ovadiah Yosef, the Kaliver Rebbe, R' Schachter, R' Lichtenstein, R' Schwartz, etc. etc., along with their names.

Comment: Oh yes, I see what you're saying. It's like jake's comment up above.

Comment: @Daniel, that's exactly what I thought you meant in the question. If not, maybe edit?

Comment: @SethJ, yes it is. I just for some reason couldn't really understand what you had written. Chalk it up to lack of sleep.

Comment: @msh210 Megillah 19b?

Comment: @DoubleAA, yes, just before the _mishna_; thanks. (Not a verse in _Ezra_. I was confusing it with _daf_ 3, which cites _Ezra_, but that _g'mara_ is irrelevant here.)

Comment: it is worth reading the essay here: http://books.google.co.cr/books?id=r54bbqIYAZgC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA29#v=onepage&q&f=false -- it discusses the issue brought up in the second and third paragraph of this answer, and also offers a couple answers of how it could still be a "Chiddush" if it was already told to Moshe on Sinai.

Comment: Would the downvoters care to leave a comment? My point above was to demonstrate that it cannot be _literally_ true. The Gemara does not contradict this.