# Where do the words יְרִידַת הַדּוֹרוֹת come from?

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, hebrew

There is a term in Judaism called יְרִידַת הַדּוֹרוֹת, *the diminishing spiritual level of subsequent generations*.

Where do the words יְרִידַת הַדּוֹרוֹת originate from? Is it *posuk, mishna* or *gemara* etc.?

Comment: Are you sure there is such a concept?

Comment: You mix 3 different things here: term, words and idea. Please, pick one and use it in your title and question body. It is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: The term originates from the frierdikke doros, obviously.

Comment: Who vowelized that?

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel: me.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83068/1739

Answer (score 4):

Someone I know with access to the Bar Ilan database told me the earliest source that uses that phrase is [Rav Yaakov Emden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Emden) (18th century).

> **מור וקציעה סימן פח**
>
> דף מ"ה ע"א. והרמב"ם בסוף הל' ק"ש נתן טעם לדבר היאך היה כח לריב"ב לבטל תקנת עזרא. הטעם ההוא הביאו הרב"י להלן בסוף עמוד זה. ואני אומר בלשון זה, עזרא לדורו תקן שהיו גבורי כח ועמדו בתקנתו כל זמן שיכלו רוב צבור לעמוד בה. אח"כ **בירידת הדורות** בימי האמוראים שירדה חולשה לעולם הוכרחו לבטלה, כדי שלא תצא ממנה קולא שיבואו להתבטל מק"ש ומתורה ומתפלה בשביל כך. על כן ממילא בטלה לה, דגזירה שאין רוב הצבור יכולין [לעמוד] בה מעצמה היא בטלה, כדילפינן [הוריות ג, ב] מקרא [מלאכי ג, ט] במארה כו', ועזרא גופיה אדעתא דהכי לא גזר. ועיין לחם שמים ריש פ"ה דמעשר שני.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know for sure if this is the first source, however it is the earliest source I could find. Although it does not say יְרִידַת הַדּוֹרוֹת it does say נתקלקלו הדורות.

Bava Basra 91b

"אמר רבי יוחנן: נהירנא כד הוו מטיילין טליא וטלייתא בשוקא כבר שית עשרה וכבר שב עשרה, ולא הוו חטאן".

Maharsha says

"ר"ל שנתקלקלו הדורות מימי החורבן מיום ליום, וכדאמרינן: אכשר דרי?! – בתמיה".