# Earliest application of "frailty/feebleness descended upon humanity” (״ירדה חולשה לעולם״)

Tags: sources-mekorot, halacha-theory

A popular saying in various fields of *halachah* (Jewish law) is “frailty/feebleness descended upon humanity” (״ירדה חולשה לעולם״). This is perhaps most known in the area of fasting where some authorities exercise some leniency in certain situations. A simple Google or Sefaria search yields some results, the earliest of which I’ve seen is [Chaye Adam](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avraham_Danzig). What is the earliest application or usage of this term in the field of *halachah*? (Disclaimer: I don’t know if CA is the earliest.)

Unlike [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83068/15571) question (and [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104731/15571) question; HT/Dr. Shmuel) which treats a similar expression that relates more specifically to spiritual parameters, almost theosophical in nature, I am asking where the aforementioned saying is directly applied to and influences any given *halachah*.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104731/16706

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel The Yaavetz quoted [there](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/104788/15571) is indeed an example where *halachah* was influenced. Go ahead and post as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The source for this is **Megillah 21a**

> תנו רבנן: מימות משה ועד רבן גמליאל לא היו למדין תורה אלא מעומד, משמת רבן גמליאל **ירד חולי לעולם** והיו למדין תורה מיושב. והיינו דתנן: משמת רבן גמליאל בטל כבוד תורה

The gemarra says *choli*, sickness, and not *chulsha*, weakness. It seems all the manuscripts say *choli*.

However, the **Meiri** (*ad. loc.*) quotes (or paraphrases) the gemarra as *chulsha*:

> לסמוך על מה שאמרו בסוגיא זו משמת רבן גמליאל **ירדה חולשה לעולם**

You asked for an application to *halacha*. A friend showed me this **Rashba** (Responsa 1:142), quoting a **Rashi** from somewhere:

> גם מה שאמרת שתמהת על **מה ששמעת משם רש"י ז"ל** שאין אומרין עננו בתפילת ערבית של קודם התענית שמא יאנס ויאכל ונמצא שקרן. ואמרת שבירושלמי אמרו בלילי שבת ויומו ואי משום אונס רחמנא פטריה.
>
> כדין אמרת. ובשם רש"י ז"ל לא בתפילת ערבית בלבד אמר אלא ערבית ושחרית עד המנחה ולא לחלוק על הירושלמי ועל הבריתא השנויה בפרק במה מדליקין (דף כ"ד). דתניא ימים שאין בהם קרבן מוסף כגון שני וחמישי ותעניות ומעמדות ערבית ושחרית ומנחה מתפלל שמונה עשרה ואומר מעין המאורע בשומע תפילה. אלא שהוא ז"ל נתן טעם לדבריו **מפני שעכשיו נכנסה חולשא בעולם וקרוב הדבר שיצטרך לאכול ולפיכך לא יבטח בעצמו להזכירו בתפילתו**. ומכל מקום אין אנו עושין כדבריו בשחרית ומנחה. אבל הכל נהגו כדבריו בתפילת ערבית ואף על פי שאמרו בבריתא ובירושלמי כן. ועוד אמרו יש אוכל ומתפלל תפילת תענית! ובכל כיוצא בזה פוק חזי מה צבור נוהג ונהוג כן.

He says not to say *aneinu* at *Maariv* since *chulsha* has entered the world and it's very likely a person will have to break their fast before morning.

Comment: Rashba - great source! (I say “Rashba” bec Rashi himself articulated it differently and doesn’t use this term; the Rashi referenced is most prob. [this](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Shabbat.24a.4.2?with=all&lang=bi) one.)

Comment: He says הוא נתן טעם לדבריו, sounds like Rashi

Comment: True, though the Geonim who Rashi quotes, AFAIK, don’t use that exact phraseology nor do the Rishonim who quote that Rashi ascribe it to him as such. Rashba could simply have been paraphrasing - something very common in that era [and earlier].