# Torah prohibition of Shofar on Shabbos Rosh Hashanah?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, talmud-gemara, rosh-hashanah-new-year, shofar

The Torah says Rosh Hashanah is a יום תרועה, a day of shofar blasts, and זכרון תרועה, a remembrance of shofar blasts. This seems like a contradiction.

The Gemara ([Rosh Hashanah 29b](https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_Hashanah.29b.7)) suggests that *the remembrance of shofar blasts* refers to Rosh Hashanah that falls on Shabbos. The Gemara infers that this would be a Torah prohibition. There are questions on this suggestion, and it is subsequently rejected. Blowing the shofar on Shabbos RH is merely a rabbinic prohibition.

What was the *hava amina*, initial understanding, that it would be a Torah prohibition? Why would it be forbidden? What kind of prohibition would it have been? The Gemara states it's not a *Melacha*. Would it have been a new *Melacha*? Or a side prohibition, like having your animal rest?

I'm asking not just from the *Hava Amina* but from the [Yerushalmi](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Rosh_Hashanah.18b.1) which makes the same suggestion as above to resolve the verse, and makes no mention of a rabbinic prohibition. The [Damesek Eliezer](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%92%D7%A8_(%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A7_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8)) (see below) says there's no mention in the entire Yerushalmi of a rabbinic prohibition. I heard the same fact in the name of [Rav Meir Simcha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meir_Simcha_of_Dvinsk). It sounds like the Yerushalmi sees it as a Torah prohibition.

I'm also wondering about the Biur HaGra. The Shulchan Aruch ([OC 582:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.582.6)), following the above Gemara that even though it's a rabbinic prohibition, the verse implies that there is no shofar on Shabbos, says to mention זכרון תרועה in the prayers. The [Biur HaGra](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2943) when writing the source of this halacha, says:

> רא"ש סוף ר"ה וגמרא שם כט ב' **ועי' בירושלמי שם**
>
> Rosh at the end of Rosh Hashanah, and the Gemara there 29b. And **look at the Yerushalmi there**.

Why is the Gra pointing to the Yerushalmi? He's letting you know it holds its a Torah prohibition? He holds its a Torah prohibition? Something else? Why mention it in a halacha about prayers. I looked at the Damesek Eliezer there and he wasn't so clear to me. Subsequently I saw [Rav Shmuel Bornstein](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%91_%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F) asks this in his sefer Shai LaMoreh.

*If this last question isn't connected enough to the first one I can make it a separate question*

Comment: Perhaps it's parallel to the prohibition of wearing Tefillin on Shabbat. Nothing to do with Melakha.

Comment: It is very unclear what you're asking. Please focus on one aspect.

Comment: @AlBerko what's unclear about it? I'm pretty explicit

Comment: @AlBerko He asks what the original presumption was - why would this have been a Torah prohibition? He further notes that the original presumption of the Bavli is accepted in the Yerushalmi. The only tangential question here is the one he makes a point of saying it might not be related - that the Gra, explaining the source for the Bavli’s din, points to the Yerushalmi as well, inexplicably. I’m not sure what the point of confusion is.

Answer (score 1):

The Mirkeves Hamishna (Shofar,2,8) by Rav Shlomo Chelmer (same generation as the Gra) Gives insight on the Yerushalmi:

כפי הנראה דסמך רבנו על הירושלמי הובא [בילקוט] בפרשת אמור רבי יוחנן וריש לקיש הוו מתקשין תנינן תמן יו"ט של ראש השנה שחל להיות בשבת במקדש היו תוקעין אבל לא במדינה אמרין אי דבר תורה במדינה ידחה ואי אינו דבר תורה אף במקדש לא ידחה עד דאינון יתבין מתקשיין עבר רב כהנא אמרין הא אתי מרי דשמעתא ניקום ונשאול קמון ושאלון ליה (ואיגוב) [אמר לון] כתוב אחד אומר יום תרועה יהיה לכם וכתוב אחד אומר זכרון תרועה כיצד יתקיימו שני כתובים בזמן שהוא בחול יום תרועה ובשבת זכרון תרועה עוד שם תניא רבי שמעון בן יוחאי ידחה במקדש שהם יודעים זמנו של חדש ואל ידחה במדינה שאינם יודעים זמנו של חדש דתני ר"ש בן יוחאי יום תרועה יהיה לכם ועשיתם במקום שהקרבנות קרבים ובמקום אחר הארכתי בזה. אמנם היוצא מזה לפי טעמו של רשב"י פי' המשנה אפילו בירושלים נמי תוקעין כיון דידעי בקביעא דירחי ואין סברא שיחלוק רבא אדרשב"י בפי' המשנה אלא ודאי דה"ק רבא דרבנן הוא דגזרו משום שבות במקום דאיכא ספקא אם קדשו הבי"ד את החדש ולא רצו לגזור במקום דידעינן בקביעא דירחא לעקור עשה דאורייתא ובהכי ניחא קושיית התוס' בד"ה אבל כפי תירוץ ועוד י"ל שתירצו ומבואר המשך התוס' שפירשו אבל לא במדינה לא בירושלים וכו' וא"ת ומאי שנא מלולב וכו' ואח"כ כתבו ועוד י"ל וכו' פי' וא"כ פי' במקדש אפילו בירושלים. ואפשר דרשב"י נמי מדבריהם קאמר וכדרבא והא דתני רשב"י דרשא דסמיכות לועשיתם אסמכתא בעלמא הוא:

The Rambam says that in the time of the Beis Hamikdash the Shofar was blown in all of Yerushalayim. The reason is that the Yerushalmi quotes Rabbi Shimon Bar Yochai that since in Yerushalayim they new when Rosh Chodesh was fixed, the Rabbanan allowed the Blowing of the Shofar despite Rosh hashana falling on Shabbos. There would have been a Gezeira not to do a Shvus (incase somone will fix a shofar or bring it through a Reshus Harabim which is a melacha) which is a Seyag on Melochos deoraisa but since there is an Asmachta of "yom Terua," this means that Shofar overrides Shabbos only if it is 100% sure its Rosh Hashana i.e in Yerushalayim where the begining of the month is fixed. (Just like Mila overrides shabbos Bayom Hashemini though that is Deoraisa)
Outside Yerushalayim however where they are not sure if it is Rosh Hashana they can't blow the shofar in safek and the passuk "zichron terua"applies which is an Asmachta of not blowing the Shofar. So Rava in the Bavli 29b holds of the Braisa of Rashbi Quoted in the Yerushalmi and There is no opinion that says Shofar cannot be Blown min Hatorah.

As for the Damesek Eliezer Ohr Sameach i did not see them so i do not know what they mean. I am just trying to bring enlightment on the Terms of the Yerushalmi that they do not litterally mean Deoraisa Shofar should overide Shabbos because Shofar is a Shvus as explained By Mirkeves Hamishne

Comment: Does the mirkeves hamishnah justify his reading considering there is no mention of gezeira or asmachta in the yerushalmi and without the bavli I would have read it at face value that it's doraisa?

Comment: @robev to Mirkeves Hamishne the Peshat in Yerushalmi is Poshut so does not bring justification but i think this is why: if Blowing the Shofar was Assur Deoraisa on Shabbos as the Possuk says "Zichron Terua", then how could the Braisa in the name of Rabbi Shimon allow it in Yerushalayim just because of an external Sevora that they know exactly when the month starts? R' Yochanan Reish Lakish and R' Kahana are not arguing with a Tanna, as Rabbi Shimon is not brought as a question to "zichron Terua", rather a proof to it that outside Yerushalayim we do Not Blow the Shofar Misofeik issur derabanan.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Yerushalmi:

> גמרא ר' אבא בר פפא א"ר יוחנן ורשב"ל הוון יתיבון מקשיי אמרין תנינן י"ט
>   של ר"ה שחל להיות בשבת במקדש היו תוקעין אבל לא במדינה אין דבר תורה הוא
>   אף בגבולין ידחה אין לית הוא דבר תורה אף במקדש לא ידחה עבר כהנא אמרין
>   הא גברא רבה דנישאול ליה.  אתון שאלון ליה אמר לון כתוב אחד אומר (במדבר
>   כט) יום תרועה וכתוב אחד אומר (ויקרא כג) זכרון תרועה הא כיצד בשעה שהוא
>   חל בחול יום תרועה בשעה שהוא חל בשבת זכרון תרועה מזכירין אבל לא תוקעין.
>   ר' זעירה מפקד לחבריי' עולון ושמעין קליה דרבי לוי דרש.  דלית איפשר דהוא
>   מפיק פרשתיה דלא אולפן.  ועל ואמר קומיהון כתוב אחד אומר יום תרועה וכתוב
>   אחד אומר זכרון תרועה הא כיצד בשעה שהוא חל בחול יום תרועה בשעה שהוא חל
>   בשבת זכרון תרועה מזכירין אבל לא תוקעין.  מעתה אף במקדש לא ידחה תנא
>   (שם) באחד לחדש.  מעתה אפילו במקום שהן יודעין שהוא באחד לחדש ידחה.  תני
>   רשב"י (שם) והקרבתם במקום שהקרבנות קריבין.  אמרין חבריי' קומי ר' יונה
>   והכתיב (ויקרא כה) והעברת שופר תרועה בחדש השביעי וגו' אמר לון זו את
>   מעביר בארצכם הא אחרת לא.  אמרין ליה או נאמר זו אתם מעבירין בארצכם הא
>   אחרת בין בארץ בין בח"ל.  א"ר יונה אילו הוה כתיב תעבירו שופר בארצכם
>   הייתי אומר כאן מיעט ובמקום אחר ריבה אלא בכל ארצכם כאן ריבה ובמקום אחר
>   מיעט:

As you can see, the Yerushalmi doesn't just use the Pesukim of Zichron Teruah and Yom Teruah as a *Asmachta* (Suggestion), it actually uses it as a *Mekor* (source), in that the Yerushalmi asked on those Pessukim why Shofar is only blown on Shabbos במקדש in the Beis Hamikdoshand not במדינה the rest of Eretz Ysroel cause based on those Pessukim there shouldn't be a difference, and answered:

> תני רשב"י (שם) והקרבתם, במקום שהקרבנות קריבין

Comment: It's my first answer on this site and my English isn't great, so feel free to Edit

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but you didn't answer the question. I also already brought the Yerushalmi in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

R. Levi Yitzchak Schneersohn zt"l (father of the last Lubavitcher Rebbe zt"l) explains:

> וְעַל פִּי נִגְלֶה יֵשׁ לוֹמַר שֶׁיְּתָרְצוּ כָּךְ, הַיְינוּ שֶׁהֵם יְפָרְשׁוּ גַּם כֵּן שֶׁהַפָּסוּק דְּשַׁבָּתוֹן זִכְרוֹן תְּרוּעָה מַיְירֵי בְּשַׁבָּת כְּמוֹ שֶׁכָּתוּב שַׁבָּתוֹן, הַיְינוּ כְּשֶׁרֹאשׁ הַשָּׁנָה חָל בְּשַׁבָּת.‏ אַךְ הַפֵּרוּשׁ דְּזִכְרוֹן תְּרוּעָה אֵינוֹ כְּמוֹ שֶׁפֵּרֵשׁ ר' לֵוִי בַּר לַחְמָא שֶׁרַק יַזְכִּיר אֶת הַתְּרוּעָה, דְּהַיְינוּ אֲמִירַת הַמִּקְרָאוֹת שֶׁל הַתְּרוּעָה אֶלָּא הַפֵּרוּשׁ דְּזִכָּרוֹן הוּא שֶׁצָּרִיךְ לִהְיוֹת זִכָּרוֹן שֶׁיִּזְכֹּר שֶׁשַּׁבָּת הַיּוֹם וְלֹא יַעֲבִירֶנּוּ ד׳ אַמּוֹת בִּרְשׁוּת הָרַבִּים וְאָז מֻתָּר תְּרוּעָה דְּהַיְינוּ לִתְקֹעַ, וְהַתּוֹרָה אֵינָהּ גּוֹזֶרֶת שֶׁמָּא לֹא יִזְכֹּר וְיִשְׁכַּח.‏ אוֹ יִתְפָּרֵשׁ זִכְרוֹן תְּרוּעָה הַיְינוּ שֶׁיִּזְכֹּר וְיֵדַע אֶת הַתְּרוּעָה דְּהַיְינוּ שֶׁיְּהֵא בָּקִי בָּהּ וְאָז מֻתָּר תְּרוּעָה דְּהַיְינוּ לִתְקֹעַ כִּי אִם לֹא כֵן הֲרֵי צָרִיךְ לִהְיוֹת שֶׁיֵּלֵךְ אֵצֶל הַבָּקִי וְיַעֲבִירֶנּוּ ד׳ אַמּוֹת בִּרְשׁוּת הָרַבִּים, וְהַתּוֹרָה אֵינָהּ גּוֹזֶרֶת אֶת הַבָּקִי מִשּׁוּם שֶׁאֵינוֹ בָּקִי,‏ וְרַבָּנָן גּוֹזְרִים שֶׁמָּא לֹא יִזְכֹּר,‏ וְגוֹזְרִים הַבָּקִי מִשּׁוּם שֶׁאֵינוֹ בָּקִי.‏

As adapted in Chayenu, Emor 5783:

> The “remembrance” in the verse from Vayikra can thus be understood in a different vein than R’ Levi bar Lachma does: not as a reference to the verses regarding the shofar, but as enjoining us to remember Shabbos itself and its multifarious laws. Taken in this way, then, the three words שבתון זכרון תרועה can be understood as follows: שבתון, when Rosh Hashanah occurs on the *Shabbos* day, on which all work ceases, זכרון, be sure to *remember* that it is Shabbos, and then תרועה, you will be able to *blow* the shofar without fear of violating the holy day. And the opposite is also implied: if you are apt to forget Shabbos or its laws, do not blow the shofar. Thus **the Torah’s phraseology already suggests the concern expressed by Rabbah,** which eventually the Sages found prevalent enough to issue a sweeping prohibition against blowing the shofar on Shabbos.
>
> Alternatively, the “remembrance” may be taken to refer to the rules and techniques of shofar blowing, yielding a somewhat different understanding: when Rosh Hashanah occurs on *Shabbos*, if you *remember* how to blow and are not in need of instruction by an expert, then you may *blow*, but otherwise you may not. On this reading **the verse is drawing a distinction between the expert and the non-expert, banning the latter from sounding the shofar on Shabbos, out of fear that in his eagerness to do the mitzvah he will inadvertently desecrate Shabbos by carrying**; the Sages, then, simply extended this ban and made it more universal, thereby safeguarding the sanctity of Shabbos.