# Why aren't Zeraim or Toharos included in the Bavli as Mishnayos?

Tags: history, mishna, talmud-bavli

Whatever the reason, [there is no Gemara on most of Zeraim and Toharos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7165/why-no-talmud-bavli-on-zeraim-or-taharot).  Why, though, were the mishnayos themselves not included in their entireties in the redacted Talmud Bavli?

It seems strange that one could learn the entire Talmud Bavli without having thus learned the entire Mishna.

Comment: Just because they're not included in daf yomi doesn't mean they aren't part of Shas

Comment: @ba, it's not just a daf-yomi thing.  My Soncino edition of "the talmud" (bavli) doesn't include them either, though its mishna does.

Comment: @MonicaCellio ([This one](http://halakhah.com/) does.) But that may have been a matter of convenience, by printing all the mishnayos (which are small) together to make one big volume. Whether it's printed there, though, doesn't affect what it is (Yerushalmi Shekalim being printed with Bavli Pesachim doesn't make it Bavli).

Comment: It seems strange that one could learn through all of Bavli without going through all of Tanach, but they aren't printed together.

Comment: that's a publisher's decision.... CYLJB - See your local Jewish bookstore :)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14186

Comment: @DoubleAA the Gemara is essentially a commentary on the Mishna - A Chumash with Rashi doesn't omit the verses on which Rashi doesn't comment.

Comment: @yoel But a Chumash Bereishit doesn't include Shemot. Why should a Talmud Pesachim include Peah? I thought you were asking on an ideological level: this is the way we _should_ print our texts.

Comment: @DoubleAA this volume is only Bereshis but the whole Chumash still contains Shemos.  I think I am asking on an ideological level, but maybe not necessarily about printing - I'm asking why these Mishnayos aren't part of the Talmud.

Comment: @Yoel, that's the answer. Because they are Mishnayoth, _not_ Talmud.

Answer (score 2):

They are included in Talmud Bavli (it is in the back of Berachos), if your edition doesn't have it it's probably because they wanted to save money on the printing (and figured you would buy a Mishnayos to learn those Masechtos).

Answer (score 0):

The Mishna and Talmud do not break up the Mishna chapters the same way, and don't even break up Halachot the same way.

Mishna really needs to be studied seperately from the Talmud if one wants to study Mishna.  If you want to study Talmud, you study the Talmud and there is no reason to include Mishnaot which have no Gemora.

Comment: There's still a broader "why" on your answer, though... any idea?

Comment: @yoel why not?  What purpose does having mishanot which have no gemora be added to the book?  Printing was not cheap back then.

Comment: fair enough....