# Why were masechtot of mishna without gemara included (or not) in Talmud Bavli and daf yomi?

Tags: talmud-gemara, pirke-avot-ethicsof, daf-yomi, eduyot

I would like to better understand why certain tractates of mishna which don't have gemara were selected or not for inclusion in Talmud Bavli and/or daf yomi?

Here is what I understand

- most tractates in *seder Zeraim and Taharot* don't have gemara and are not included in Talmud Bavli or daf yomi, *Berachot* and *Niddah* are the exceptions (see [this MY question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7165/why-no-talmud-bavli-on-zeraim-or-taharot))
- **Shekalim** has gemara in Talmud Yerushalmi but not in Talmud Bavli. Its Talmud Yerushalmi version is included in Talmud Bavli. Answers [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14188/11501) suggests this might be to help learn the entire *seder Moed* since it is the only tractate missing
- **Kinnim** and **Middot** don't have gemara in the Bavli or Yerushalmi but their Mishna version is nevertheless included in the *daf yomi* cycle and printed in many (all?) editions of the gemara. The [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14188/11501) above and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinnim) (for Kinnim) suggest this might be to help learn the entire *seder Kodashim* since they are the only tractate missing
- **Eduyot** and **Pirkei Avot** are not included in Talmud Bavli or *daf yomi*. If they were, they would enable to complete the entire *seder Nezikin*

So why are Pirkei Avot and Eduyot not included in Talmud Bavli and/or *daf yomi* as part of Seder Nezikin?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14186/170. Also related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18597/170.

Comment: I heard that some Daf yomi siyumim get kids to finish the mishnayos to complete the whole Shas in answer to last question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why no Talmud Bavli on Zeraim or Taharot?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7165/why-no-talmud-bavli-on-zeraim-or-taharot)

Comment: @DonielF Isn't that question asking why there was no Bavli created in the first place, while this question is asking why later organizers didn't incorporate non-Bavli material into the Bavli?

Comment: @Alex I didn’t gather that at al from here

Comment: @DonielF *why certain tractates of mishna which don't have gemara were selected or not for inclusion in Talmud Bavli and/or daf yomi* as opposed to *why did the Amoraim not discuss them the way they did Kodashim*

Comment: @DonielF the duplicate you mention speaks of Seder Zeraim and Taharot - my question is focused on Nezikin - the rest is background per suggestion of DoubleAA

Answer (score 1):

Pirkei Avot and Eduyot are printed in the back of the Bavli for Maseches Avodah Zara, along with the Masechtos Ketanos, or small tractates.

The mishnayos of Zeraim and Taharos printed in the Gemara have different commentaries than the ones printed in mishnayos.